# Can't get selected text from webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to get selected text from webview with below code but this returning null.please let me now that where is the problem in below code.

in this code index.html is a html file inside my sdcard/dheeraj/index.html folder.

```
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.res.AssetManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.content.ClipboardManager;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.ActionMode;

        import android.view.KeyEvent;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.widget.Toast;


    public class AddToNotesWithWebViewActivity extends Activity
    {

        AssetManager assetManager;
        WebView webview;
        String line, line1 = "", finalstr = "";
        int i = 0;
        private ActionMode mActionMode = null;
        private ClipboardManager clipboard;
        boolean mark_text=false;

        @Override
        public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
            if (mActionMode == null) {
                mActionMode = mode;
                Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
                // Remove the default menu items (select all, copy, paste, search)
                menu.clear();

                mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_to_notes_menu, menu);
            }

            super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
        }


        public void onContextualMenuItemClicked(MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.add_to_notes_menu_item:

                    clipboard =
                            (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    emulateShiftHeld(webview);
                    selectedText();




                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }

            // This will likely always be true, but check it anyway, just in case
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                mActionMode.finish();
            }
        }

        private void selectedText()
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, clipboard.getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode = null;
            super.onActionModeFinished(mode);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.ac_add_to_notes_web_view);
            webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view_browser);



            WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webview.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dheeraj/index.html");

        }

        private void emulateShiftHeld(WebView view)
        {

         try
            {
                KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
                shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);

                registerForContextMenu(view);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
            }
        }

    }
```

Please help....?????????

Comment: Are you added permission code in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer following code :

```
 package com.Demo.SelectText;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     WebView mWebView;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://devemat-androidprogramming.blogspot.com/");

        }

        private static final int SELECTTEXT_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

         menu.add(0, SELECTTEXT_MENU_ID, 0, "Select Text");

         return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
         super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
         return true;
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
         switch(item.getItemId()){
         case SELECTTEXT_MENU_ID:
              SelectText();
              return true;
         }
         return true;
        }

        public void SelectText(){
        try{
          KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = 
                   new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,     
                   KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
          shiftPressEvent.dispatch(mWebView);
      }catch(Exception e){
          throw new AssertionError(e);
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: i have already try this code.this code add menu item (Select Text )before select the text.and after select the text there are by default action mode in menu.my need is that after select the text there will a option in menu Select Text and after clicking on that selected text will be shown in toast.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void getMyText(String myText) {
          // this is called from JS
             System.out.println(myText);
       }

  }

     private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            <at> Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            }  


      Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:window.cpjs.getMyText(document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML);void(0);");

        }
    }
```